# What can I put on an unfinished cabinet that will not get a lot of use

Tags: finishing

This cabinet will not get a lot of use. More of a storage cabinet that will have a lamp and cable box. I just need some sort of finish. Really don’t want to change the color.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just too broad of a question. What finish do _you_ want? Where or how is the cabinet going to be used? What sort of wood e.g., is this all solid wood, or a veneer, or MDF? What finishing skills do you have? How much time and space do you have?

Comment: Make sure you search the previous Q&A for finishing tips. Your only criteria here, that you don't want to change the colour, usually means something _other_ than an oil-based finish. There is lots of advice in the other Q&A about clear urethane finishes that would suit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. How about nothing? There's no rule that wood must have finish on it, and in the past it was actually very common for utilitarian items to remain unfinished. Do note that wood and wood products of all kinds, including ply, MDF and chipboard/particleboard, will naturally change colour over time by themselves. Generally anything light in colour darkens, and often goes more amber-ish or tan, or a deeper beige/light brown, with exposure to light. The more light the faster and more pronounced the effect.